# Upper thigh pain caused by running?

Tags: running, pain, thigh

I run about 8-12 km a day in about 70-90 minutes every morning.I find that I have been having pain in the upper thigh(from mid-thigh to just above the knee) and along the sides of the thigh.This causes a sharp pain when using the stairs or when trying to walk/run,to put it simply it hurts when I try and lift my leg and extend it completely.

I would like to know what causes this issue,what can I do to alleviate this(if possible) and 
what excersize I could do in the meantime(Im not running because of the pain).

I ask here because, as revealed by a Google Search there seem to be several different kinds of knee pains that occur to runners and I wanted a little bit of specific advice to figure out if it is serious?

Comment: Is it the inner side?

Comment: @s3v3ns It is on outer side of the thigh,the inner thigh has no pain,it is only the outer side of the thigh and the sides closer to the outer side.

Comment: Then you should go see a PT, or take a few days easy and see if that relives the pain. From what i understand it does not seem to be any joint pain too of any sort.

Answer (score 2):

With the amount you're running (daily, 1-1.5 hours) it is most likely that you have developed IT band syndrome.  It is an inflammation of the ilio-tibial band as it passes over the lateral epicondyle.  In other words a ligament is sore on the side of your leg just above the knee joint.  The pain is in non weight bearing so as you straighten your knee rather than bending or squatting -- you can tell if you have IT band syndrome when the outside of your knee hurts when you bend your knee at a 45 degree angle. There are several biomechanical reasons that can't be diagnosed over the net so go see your PT or sports doc.

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations like ITB (iliotibial band) without explaining. Don't assume your audience knows what you are referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can figure out if it is serious is to go to a doctor or a PT.

If you don't want to do that, you could try foam rolling the area. If it is related to muscles or tendons that can help.